# jQuery steps won't render correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>TEsT</title>    
</head>
<body>
<div id="wizard">
    <h1>First Step</h1>
    <div>First Content</div>

    <h1>Second Step</h1>
    <div>Second Content</div>
</div>

    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
<script src="homepage.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#wizard").steps();
});
```

The (un-extraordinary) Rendition:
[image: jQuery Steps]

Comment: looks like you're missing some css https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/blob/master/demo/css/jquery.steps.css

Comment: How should it be rendering? Is the jQuery code in the jquery.steps.min.js file? Can you setup a jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Comment: @JayBlanchard No jQuery code is included before the 'steps'.

Comment: @andrew, you seem to be right, but I failed to find any mention of css on the plugin's website, neither was it included with the download.

Comment: Where is the jQuery code that you wrote?

Comment: try changing the `div` tag inside `#wizard` to `section` tag

Comment: @JayBlanchard My code is in hompage.js, which is included. The code itself is posted above: $(document).ready(function(){
$("#wizard").steps();
});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should include following css file in your plugin:

https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/blob/master/demo/css/jquery.steps.css

Also 
try changing the `div` tag inside `#wizard` to `section` tag

Comment: main.css was also needed.

Comment: Had the same problem. It seems the main.css file came from the HTML5 Boilerplate.